# How do I improve this SQL query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

It's been awhile since I worked with SQL, and I can't remember the best way get data from linked tables. What is the best way to get data from tables Cat and Bat?

```
Apple
---------
batId
catId

Bat
---------
id
batField1
batField2
batField3

Cat
---------
id
catField1
catField2
catField3
```

I'm trying to get batField1, batField3, and catField1.
This is my current query

```
SELECT b.batField1, b.batField3, c.catField1
FROM Apple AS a, Bat as b, Cat as c
WHERE a.batId = b.id OR a.catId = c.id;
```

Comment: How do you expect those to merge? Can you show the expected end result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT b.batField1, b.batField3, c.catField1
FROM Apple AS a
LEFT JOIN Bat as b ON A.BatID = b.ID
LEFT JOIN Cat as c ON A.CatID = c.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT b.batField1, b.batField3, c.catField1
FROM Bat b
INNER JOIN Apple a ON b.Id = a.batID
INNER JOIN Cat c ON a.catId = c.id
```